# How to run Open Sora in browser via Jupyter Notebook or similar cloud setup?

Tags: text-to-video, sora

So it looks like while waiting for **OpenAI's Sora** to arrive we got something even better - **Collosal-AI's [Open Sora](https://hpc-ai.com/blog/open-sora)**!

Okay, to be fair it's not really possible to judge which is better at this point since Sora is not available yet. And we will have to consider not only image quality but how flexible it is, and how faithfully it honors our prompts and so on.

Those details aside, an open source competitor before the highly publicized Sora is very exciting to say the least.

But wait, it appears we have not *one*, but *two* open source competitors!? There is also **PKU-YuanGroup's [Open-Sora-Plan](https://github.com/PKU-YuanGroup/Open-Sora-Plan)** literally being updated as I type this.

With new toys coming out by the day it can be hard to keep up with what the latest is. Please forgive me if I've missed any important details.

Can **Open Sora** (or **Open-Sora-Plan**) be run in the browser through a Jupyter Notebook or similar server-client application? There don't seem to be tutorials posted for configuring them yet, and I doubt these will run on my local hardware. But I am dying to try them out. What are my options?